# Swift 4 Programming Language, inout parameter is not working for FunctionType as Paramter

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-playground

This is the sample code from swift documentation. I am learning swift language, and I saw the functiontype as parameter, The sample code does not have inout keyword. But I am trying to use this with inout paramter, but the below sample is not working as expected.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html (Function Types as Return Types)

```
//Function Types as Return Types
func stepForward(_ input: inout Int) -> Int {
    return input + 1
}
func stepBackward(_ input: inout Int) -> Int {
    return input - 1
}
func chooseStepFunction(backward: Bool) -> (inout Int) -> Int {
    let a = backward ? stepBackward : stepForward
    return a
}
var currentValue = 3
let moveNearerToZero = chooseStepFunction(backward: currentValue > 0)
print(moveNearerToZero(&currentValue))
print(currentValue)
```

Actual output 
    2
    3

Expected output
    2
    2

Because CurrentValue is inout paramter. Passing the currentValue as 3 initially prints value 2 using stepBackward() method

and I want to maintain the value after the decrement.

But the currentValue is not maintained here.

Comment: I think, Apple documentation needs some correction.

Comment: @Kamran actually the OP didn't try the exact example in the documentation. Instead he is trying to understand `inout` concept using the example modified by himself.

Comment: @Vishnu what's the point of using parameter as `inout` if you aren't really changing the value of the parameter inside the function?

Comment: @nayem Yes, actually there is no use of `inout` in that example as it is to demonstrate how to return function types. So it might confuse newbies.

Comment: @nayem, thanks for pointing the mistake, the input value is not changed and it is my mistake, just learning new. Accepted the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are not actually assigning value to parameter after applying arithmetics you are just returning new value without assigning it. Try the following code

```
//Function Types as Return Types
func stepForward(_ input: inout Int) -> Int {
    input += 1
    return  input
}
func stepBackward(_ input: inout Int) -> Int {
    input -= 1
    return  input 
}
func chooseStepFunction(backward: Bool) -> (inout Int) -> Int {
    let a = backward ? stepBackward : stepForward
    return a
}
var currentValue = 3
let moveNearerToZero = chooseStepFunction(backward: currentValue > 0)
print(moveNearerToZero(&currentValue))
print(currentValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it without return anything. Just pass current value in function  and update the value it will automatically update current value.

```
func stepForward(_ input: inout Int)   {
  input = input + 1
}

func stepBackward(_ input: inout Int)  {
   input = input - 1
}

func chooseStepFunction(backward: Bool, currentValue: inout Int)   {
   backward ? stepBackward(&currentValue) : stepForward(&currentValue)
}

var currentValue = 3
chooseStepFunction(backward: currentValue > 0, currentValue: &currentValue)
print(currentValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you never changed the currentValue value !

you should change the currentValue value in chooseStepFuction method !

```
chooseStepFunction(backward: currentValue > 0,
                   currentValue: &currentValue)
```